# How to save camera images in sqlite database using content providers?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am making an example inventory app, one string and two integer values are being stored in the database using content provider and then being populated on a listview and through it’s `setOnItemClickListener()` on list’s detail view, now I want to add a camera taken image to each row from the editorActivity and inflate the image on list's detail view, I know a `BLOB` type is used to add a bitmap image which is converted to byteArray and then stored in the table but it’s still not clear to me specially concerning content providers, sorry for not explaining this clearly any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Right now an image is taken by the camera and inflated on an imageView, it is not being stored within the table.

EditorActivity.Java

```
public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

EditText mProductNameEditText;
EditText mProductQuantityEditText;
EditText mProductPriceEditText;
Button mSaveProductButton;
ImageButton mPhotoButton;
ImageView mPhotoImage;
Bitmap mPhoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

    mProductNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    mProductQuantityEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_quantity);
    mProductPriceEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_price);

    mPhotoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inventory_editor_photo);
    mPhotoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.inventory_editor_camera);

    imageButtonClicker();

    mSaveProductButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_product);

    saveButtonClicker();
}

public void imageButtonClicker(){

    mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mPhoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mPhotoImage.setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
    }
}

public void saveButtonClicker(){

    mSaveProductButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            insertInventory();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void insertInventory(){

    String productNameString = mProductNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String productQuantityString = mProductQuantityEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String productPriceString = mProductPriceEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(productNameString) || TextUtils.isEmpty(productQuantityString) || TextUtils.isEmpty(productPriceString)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: at-least one or all of the Inventory fields were blank.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_NAME, productNameString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_QUANTITIY, productQuantityString);
    values.put(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_PRICE, productPriceString);

    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

    if (newUri == null) {
        // If the row ID is -1, then there was an error with insertion.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving Inventory Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast with the row ID.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inventory Product saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

InventoryDbHelper.java

```
public class InventoryDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Inventory.db";

public InventoryDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String SQL_CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE=
            "CREATE TABLE " + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    InventoryContract.InventoryEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_NAME + " TEXT  NOT NULL, " +
                    InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_QUANTITIY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                    InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_PRICE + " INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                    InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB," +
                    InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_KEY_TAG + " TEXT);";


    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_INVENTORY_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPhoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            mPhotoImage.setImageBitmap(mPhoto);

     ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    mPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "images" + today_date + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        //5
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        fo.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Servicing.this, "Oops not able to capture image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }``
        }
    }


save image to sqlite add this code in your insertInventory()

   if (mPhoto != null) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    mPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
                    values.put(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_KEY_IMAGE,stream.toByteArray());
                } else {
                   //do what you want
                }
```